# What does the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance" mean in Xcode

Tags: xcode

What does it mean `"unrecognized selector sent to instance"` in `Xcode`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the “unrecognized selector sent to instance” error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152651/what-does-the-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error-mean)

Answer (score 18):

It means, method is not defined or on the other-way, calling a method on the wrong object.

classic example of this error is missing of ':' in selector call.

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self
                action:@selector(DatePickerDoneClick)];
```

Here,

```
action:@selector(DatePickerDoneClick:)
```

is expected rather than

```
action:@selector(DatePickerDoneClick)
```

Comment: Im new to iOS programming, and this answer really helped me :) its such a tiny difference that can be overlooked

Answer (score 13):

If you've deleted and re-created buttons on the Storyboard, you may have the button linked to two different methods: the old (deleted) one, and the new one. This has happened to me many times.

To fix:
1) In XCode/IB, view the Storyboard.
2) Click on the button that is causing the exception.
3) On the far-right panel, click the 'connector' icon.  (A circle with an arrow in it, as of Apr-2015).
4) Assuming you're linking to the action "Touch Up Inside", make sure only ONE method is linked.  An [x] will appear next to each, so if there are two, kill the one that no longer exists.

Answer (score 6):

In my case it means I did not understand (for two days) a very simple requirement of the handler (selector, function):
I had left off the ...**:(NSNotification*)notification**... in my selector (function).

In the end it is just a self.stupidMistake (or programming tired while trying to understand a new thing in iOs/xCode).  I read the docs at apple, I read many, many here at stackoverflow and read all kinds of other pages from the search results and just kept overlooking the fact that I had:
in the viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addOberserver:self selector:@selector(myHandler:) name:@"UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification" object:nil];
```

in the .h (declaration) and .m (real code) I had invented:

```
-(void)myHandler { ... }
```

This generated the **unrecognized selector sent to instance** (crash and debug output) at runtime (no errors or warnings in xcode).  Then I spent almost two whole days trying to figure out the error and the error was:

```
-(void)myHandler:(NSNotification*)notification { ... }
```

Hope it helps anyone else stuck - it is a syntax thing (your Selector or Handler or Function or whatever you want to call it) **must** take a (NSNotification*) 'object' as a parameter whether you use it or not; and xcode (4.2 w/iOs SDK 5.0) does not generate any errors or warnings about this 'mistake'.

Answer (score 5):

I think this error is due to calling a function in class which is not declared in the class.

Answer (score 5):

It means that you have called a method on an object which does not support that method.

The reason it says 'unrecognised selector' is that method invocation is implemented by a message sending mechanism. The part of the message that contains the method name is called the selector.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's when you call a selector on instance of method that doesn't belong to this instance.
maybe I'm wrong I'm not sure, it's been a while since I've coded anything in xcode.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was just `Xcode` not bothering to compile the code. Apple obviously doesn't think iOS development is complicated enough, so they have to build extra flakiness into the IDE.

I am told that `SHIFT+COMMAND+K` to clean the build can be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error due to not assigning the custom class to the view in the Interface Builder.

```
 NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EventsFilterView" owner:self options:nil];
 self.filters = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

The variable `self.filters` was assigned to the `EventFilterView` class but the actual view in the xib file was not.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why this can occur:

ONE:The method is declared in the .h, but does not exist in the .m. The compiler does not complain, but during execution you face that crash.Please,Check this out:

1. The method is implemented in the m.
2. The method signature is exactly the same.
3. There is not a semi-colon at the end of the method signature.

TWO:If you are calling a delegated method, check if this method is really implemented.

I use to have this error when I modify the signature, but I forgot to update the signature method on the implementation file .m

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the issue was my ".m" class containing the unknown selector wasn't in the "Build Phases / Compile Sources" list.
I added it and everything was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I was stuck on this problem for days, for me, as Javier mentioned, my signature was slightly different because I added throws to my @IBAction func in the view controller I used in the storyboard.