# setAnnotation - unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

While running on a device after tapping the search button, I am getting this error but it is working in the simulator.

```
2013-03-08 17:58:33.981 IPAD[2661:907] Slider values are:min:5000.000000 and max:500000.000000
2013-03-08 17:58:33.989 IPAD[2661:907] +[SBJsonStreamWriter initialize] NSCache supported
2013-03-08 17:58:35.278 IPAD[2661:907] count is 806
2013-03-08 17:58:35.289 IPAD[2661:907] strcount is 806
2013-03-08 17:58:35.831 IPAD[2661:907] -[REVClusterPin setAnnotation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd36e00
2013-03-08 17:58:35.833 IPAD[2661:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[REVClusterPin setAnnotation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd36e00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x32f432a3 0x3addc97f 0x32f46e07 0x32f45531 0x32e9cf68 0x33d5f18b 0x33d5eeb1 0x33d5bac7 0x33d5eb1b 0x59eb5 0x69201 0x34d6a595 0x34dbf14b 0x34dbf091 0x34dbef75 0x34dbee99 0x34dbe5d9 0x34dbe4c1 0x34dacb93 0x34dac833 0xa90f7 0x9eebd 0x3387e6fd 0x337be1f9 0x337be115 0x32c2045f 0x32c1fb43 0x32c47fcb 0x32e8974d 0x32c4842b 0x32bac03d 0x32f18683 0x32f17ee9 0x32f16cb7 0x32e89ebd 0x32e89d49 0x36a3c2eb 0x34d9f301 0xa1227 0x43620)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Comment: show your code for **[REVClusterPin setAnnotation:]:** and in your check if all your controls are bind to respective variables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455316/what-does-mean-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-in-xcode

Comment: have u r problem solved

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the “unrecognized selector sent to instance” error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152651/what-does-the-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error-mean)

Answer (score 0):

It's getting crashed for this

```
[REVClusterPin setAnnotation:]:
```

Most likely because, the value that you are passing here, doesn't exit.
Or you forgot to bind any of your control in your xib.

Comment: No,My problem not solved.i checked every thing.the app is working in simulator.while running in device i getting problem.