# if i run the app in ipad device i getting following error but it working in simulator

Tags: ios

2013-03-14 18:06:09.727 IPAD[5341:907] -[REVClusterPin setAnnotation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fe6a8b0
2013-03-14 18:06:09.729 IPAD[5341:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[REVClusterPin setAnnotation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fe6a8b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x32f432a3 0x3addc97f 0x32f46e07 0x32f45531 0x32e9cf68 0x33d5f18b 0x33d5eeb1 0x33d5bac7 0x33d5eb1b 0xc017d 0xcf419 0x34d6a595

Comment: What is the class kind of `REVClusterPin`?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409255/setannotation-unrecognized-selector

Comment: it's running in simulator ...

Answer (score 0):

One of the most problems if an app is running in simulator and not on device is that the simulator is not case sensitive with files from bundle. So please check if a image file is named like "Test.png" and in code you maybe write test.png. This is working in simulator but not not on device.

Hope this helps.